# Universal Property of Kernel [Proof]

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to prove the universal property below:

Let $f: M \longrightarrow N$ be a linear application. Prove that:

1. $\exists! \ell: L \longrightarrow M$ s.t. $\ell f = 0$.
2. If $\ell^{\prime}: L^{\prime} \longrightarrow M$ is a linear application such that $f \ell^{\prime}$ = 0, then there exists $u: L^{\prime} \longrightarrow L$ such that $l^{\prime} = \ell u$.

$M$ and $N$ are modules over an algebra. I'm not sure, but I think that in the first item it should be $f \ell = 0$ instead of $\ell f = 0$.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You are correct in guessing that it should be $f\ell=0$ instead of $\ell f=0$. The uniqueness in the first item is wrong, and in the second item the map $u\colon L'\rightarrow L$ should be unique. (Then it follows that the pair $(L,\ell)$ satisfying both properties is unique up to unique isomorphism.) You should also write down, what you have tried so far. What is your candidate for $L$?